# How to merge to HashSets with partially equal Objects?

Tags: java, hashset

I have an ArrayList `data` containing Objects of the type `Person`which updates every n seconds and has the total amount of existing data.
To display this data in a table i used to `clear()` an ObservableList and used `addAll(data)` to avoid GUI hickups.

I would like to use a HashSet as Observable Collection and I was wondering if there is an efficient way to update an Object from a HashSet if it is only partially equal.

**Code:**

```
class Person {
   int id;
   String name;
   int visits;  //this value can be different

   @Override
   int hashCode() {
   //...
   }

   @Override
   boolean equals() {
   //...
   }

}


class Main {
   static void main(String[] args) {
      List<Person> data = new ArrayList<>();
      data.add(new Person(1, Max, 4);
      data.add(new Person(2, Richard, 7); 
      data.add(new Person(3, Tom, 4); 

      Set<Person> set = new HashSet<>();
      set.addAll(data);

      // new Data incoming
      // could be the same Person (all 3 variables same)
      // could be existing Person but with changed variables (id stays the same)
      // could be completely new Person (new id)


   }
}
```

**Desired output:**

if new data is added with existing Person but different variables
`new Person(1, Max, 50);`
the index of this position should remove Max and add new Max with 50 visits (maybe at same position) 
Or better change variable visits to 50.

if all data is the same (checked with equals() and hashCode()): nothing should be added or removed

if new Person (with new id) isnt in HashSet it should be added

How could this be achieved?
I tried using 2 for loops (which is execution time consuming) and overriding a hashset but im not sure about that approach.

Comment: use can use the name as key in the hashmap and everytime the key already exists call an update method for that object

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a `Map`, not a `Set`.

```
  List<Person> data = new ArrayList<>();
  data.add(new Person(1, Max, 4);
  data.add(new Person(2, Richard, 7); 
  data.add(new Person(3, Tom, 4); 

  Map<Integer, Person> map = new HashMap<>();
  data.forEach(person -> map.put(person.getId(), person));

  // new Data incoming
  // could be the same Person (all 3 variables same)
  // could be existing Person but with changed variables (id stays the same)
  // could be completely new Person (new id)
  Person newPerson = ...;
  map.put(newPerson.getId(), newPerson);
```

You can use `TreeMap` if you want ordering by ID, or `LinkedHashMap` if you want ordering by order of entry.

Answer (score 1):

There is no such thing as partially equal. Your method `equals()` return `true` or `false`. In your case what you are saying that equality is determined by person id only. I.e. if you add a person with the same id nothing else matters and the two Person instances will be judged as equal even if `visits` value is different. So if you store your Person instances in the set and add a Person with id 1 - if the set already contains a Person with id 1 the old one will be replaced by new one. Also remember that `Set` has no order. If you want to keep an order either use `SortedSet` or `List`. But if you use `List` you will have to write the code that ensures that duplicates are not allowed on your own